# Как можно поставить backgroundTint, чтоб менялся фон и картинки, и текста?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Как можно поставить backgroundTint так, чтоб он распространялся на дочерние элементы?
Т.е менять цвет текста и цвет ImageView, просто поменяв backgroundTint LinearLayout

мой код:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/show_pts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_minus2sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/close"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/close">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_radialmenu_player_pts"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_semibold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:textColor="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="Показать ПТС"/>
</LinearLayout>
```